# Task execution with ExecutorService: Can I submit task within another task?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I want to submit a new task within an existing task in case of a failure(Exception), but had some issues running the code below:

```
public class TestTask implements Runnable{
private int myInt;
private ExecutorService exec;

public TestTask(int x, ExecutorService s){
    this.myInt=x;
    this.exec=s;
}

@Override
public void run() {         
    try{
        //print number if it's odd; otherwise throw exception
        if(this.myInt%2 ==0) throw new Exception();     
        else System.out.println("Asynchronous task: "+ this.myInt); //do sth

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("resubmitting..");
        //## TODO: PROBLEM??
        this.exec.execute(new TestTask(this.myInt+1, this.exec));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int NTHREADS =2;
    final ExecutorService service= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
    //run tasks
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        service.execute(new TestTask(i, service) );
    }
    //...
}
//....
```

The code compiles and runs for a few steps then throws **java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException**. Any ideas how to interpret this and how to fix? Thanks!

### [EDIT: Stack Trace added below]

```
resubmitting..
Asynchronous task: 1
resubmitting..
Asynchronous task: 3
resubmitting..
Asynchronous task: 5
resubmitting..
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task pe.ads.TestTask@4e19b97c rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@322ba3e4[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 8, completed tasks = 3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at pe.ads.TestTask.run(TestTask.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task pe.ads.TestTask@31eb494e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@322ba3e4[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 8, completed tasks = 3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at pe.ads.TestTask.run(TestTask.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Asynchronous task: 7Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task pe.ads.TestTask@35afe17b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@322ba3e4[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 6, completed tasks = 6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at pe.ads.TestTask.run(TestTask.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

resubmitting..
Asynchronous task: 9
Asynchronous task: 1
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-5" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task pe.ads.TestTask@53e64a3b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@322ba3e4[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 3, completed tasks = 8]
resubmitting..
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at pe.ads.TestTask.run(TestTask.java:26)
Asynchronous task: 1    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

### [EDIT: Resolved]

It turns out I called shutdown() right after the for loop,

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        service.execute(new TestTask(i, service) );
    }
    service.shutdown();
```

so new submitted tasks were rejected. Also learned that ThreadPoolExecutor is a better option. Thanks guys!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please post a full stack trace.

Comment: Do you shut down the pool in the code not shown?

Comment: It runs with no problems here. Using java 8

Comment: @Raffaele, Yes I did. I called shutdown() after the for loop. Once I remove it the exception disappears. How does this affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception [is thrown when a task is submitted and either](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

- the executor has been shut down
- you exceeded the maximum queue size

We can't tell without seeing the code, but likely you do one of these two things in hidden code (maybe even in `main`), and you have to fix it (btw, this behavior can be customized with [`setRejectedExecutionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setRejectedExecutionHandler%28java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler%29))

I don't know if this question is your  actual problem or a sample one, but anyway I don't think it's common practice for a task to spawn another task. You'd better restructure your code to make the caller itself submitting a new task when necessary. Not that it will fix your problem, but will certainly improve the design of your program. If you describe your domain, maybe we can help with that, too.

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele, it's sample code for practice. In the code not shown, I called shutdown() right after the for loop. Once I remove that, the code runs with no problem. So seems like the Exception was handled after the ExecutorService was shut down --isn't shutdown() expected to be effective after all tasks are done?

Comment: @pdxhiker From the javadoc: `shutdown() Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.`

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor` and include the re-submission logic there. It would be more elegant. `ThreadPoolExecutor` is well-designed and provides hook methods to do what you need. You would want to override [`ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)